# Angular Elements - Are they a lib or an app in NRWL/NX?

Tags: angular-elements, nrwl-nx, nrwl

Trying to build a suite of angular elements (web components) in an NX workspace.

I tried first as a lib, but couldn't 'build'.  I retried as an app - but I cannot create a storybook for it since its not a lib.

What's the path to peace?

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer is to make a `publishable` lib:

```
ng g @nrwl/angular:lib my-elements --publishable
```

This will create a library with the `build` architect to your workspace file, which is what you need to run `ng build my-elements`.

Comment: I tried this evening.  It seems to create a build process for a publishable library.  That build process is different than the one for an Angular Element, which is more like an app

Comment: [This project](https://github.com/manfredsteyer/ngx-build-plus) might help building Elements specifically. However, I did not try it in an Nx workspace yet.

Comment: I can not speak for nx, but angular elements build is using a angular application not a library as a base project and will not be build using ng-packagr.

Comment: @beeman - is this the approach you take? I was thinking of doing this slightly differently create a standard library (not publishable) this way other angular apps within the repo can use it like a standard module. Then create an angular application the generates the elements from the previously mentioned library.

Comment: This work out for you @JoAMoS? Looking to create a component library then an element library to produce from it. Elements work as a library or required an application setup?